# Active Record errors - Translate to another locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm developing a internationalized application, and sometimes I need to get some messages in a language that is not my default, like this:

```
I18n.t("my_message.some_attribute", :locale => :ptBR)
```

The problem is: I have an API method that creates and active record object, and I would like to render the error message from the method `full_messages`, like this:

```
my_object.errors.full_messages.uniq.to_sentence
```

The problem is, in that case, I get the message for my default language. How could I get that sentence in another language?
Thanks!

Comment: how are you passing the desired locale to the api controller?

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer... since the language come as a param to my api, in  my app controller I set the locale before_action:

```
  before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale =  params[:lang] || "en"
  end
```

This works for me